# grammar check ignoring spell check in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, grammar

I am in a situation to edit a Manual which has got more Greek terms. I am quite sure about the spellings given in that manual are correct. What all I need is to check grammar alone. But while checking the grammar by F7, spellings are also checked which is unnecessary for me, and it takes lot of time.

I think there is an option in Microsoft word to check the grammar ignoring spelling mistakes.

Does anyone know how to do grammar check ignoring spelling mistakes in Microsoft Word?

**EDITS:** Question has been elaborated.

Comment: How can you check grammar against words which do not exist? Spelling is integral to grammar.

Comment: My file has a number of Greek terms. I am sure about spelling but not in grammar. If I go with spell check (F7), Greek terms are hectic for me to check. Each time it shows me Greek term as spelling mistake.

Comment: You can add them to the dictionary during the spell check.

Comment: @fixer1234 Question has been elaborated.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below mentioned steps

1. Click the File tab, and then click Options.
2. Click Proofing.
3. Click to clear the Check spelling as you type check box.

Reference Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I want this while using F7(spell check) process

Comment: Do not think so there is such an option!

Comment: That is what I need.